# Integrate JHipster entity sub generator into an existing project

Tags: jhipster

I like the server side code generation which the entity sub generator gives you:

- Liquibase changesets
- Controller / service / repo code
- DTO's mapping etc

Is it possible to integrate it into an existing spring boot application?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, use Jhipster command to create a project (or create it at online: https://start.jhipster.tech/jdl-studio/).

You should check  https://www.jhipster.tech or check some demos https://www.jhipster.tech/video-tutorial/